# Rails 5: not rendering any respond_to json

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `byebug` in order to see if the `format.json { render json: @items.map(&:title) }` is called.

```
def search
if params[:search]
  @items = Item.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @items.map(&:title) }
byebug
  end
else
  @items = []
end
end
```

and in `byebug` when I type `@items` returns all the items but when I type`(byebug) response.body
""
(byebug)`

Thus its not retuning `json`. Any idea why this is happening and how I can solve this?

Comment: Why are you using `byebug` like that? Its wrong. Use a tests.

Comment: Response is not rendered in that action. Its more like configuring the response. It happens else where. Thus it been empty. I'd never looked in to it though. Use an external client (Postman or alike) or unit tests to check the response.

Comment: can you show the console when the request is processing ? (`Started GET ...`)